# Change body class at actual sunset time

Tags: php, jquery, themes

I have a theme switcher on my site and wish to add an "Automatic" option which changes the theme at sunset. At the moment I've done this by manually specifying the times but I was wondering if it was possible to actually do it at the actual sunset time using something similar to the PHP date_sunset() function.

```
var url, hour = new Date().getHours();
        if (hour > 8 && hour < 17) {
        $('body').removeClass().addClass('light');
        } else if (hour > 17 || hour < 8) {
        $('body').removeClass().addClass('dark');
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how would I implement it into the code above?

Also, if it is possible, would it be easy to say add 60 minutes to the sunset time, as the sunset times are usually a little before it's actually getting dark.

It is probably not possible but I knew this place would be the best place to double check!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to implement it in a JavaScript? If not, what about this code:

```
<body class="<?php echo time() < date_sunset(time()) ? 'light' : 'dark'; ?>">
```

**Improved in reaction to your comment:**

PHP

```
<body data-daypart="<?php echo time() < date_sunset(time()) ? 'day' : 'night'; ?>">
```

JS

```
var body = $('body');
body.removeClass().addClass(body.attr('data-daypart') === 'day' ? 'light' : 'dark');
```

Comment: I think so because the theme switcher has three options, Light, Dark and Automatic, and they all perform the change and also amend Local Storage settings. If I didn't use javascript I'd break the switcher, surely? I'd like to do it in my existing js if I can!

Comment: This will conflict with my existing js which sets the user's theme choice in localstorage and updates the theme switcher class to current.

I appreciate your response but I would like to complete this in javascript so it does not conflict with my theme switcher as it currently is. I simply want to amend the code in my original question to change the body class based on sunset rather than at a fixed time as shown.

The rest of the code, e.g. the manual light/dark theme I would also like to keep in the javascript.

Comment: Other solution could be sending the timestamps of sunset/sunrise to the document and changing the class with javascript when actual time reaches one of the timestamps.

Comment: Imprtant note: do all comparsion of timestamps in GMT time.

Comment: Can you help? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Your solution will conflict with my existing javascript won't it? So if a user sets Light theme, not Auto, it will still change at sunset

Comment: Shame that there was no answers for this :(

Comment: You should paste the whole JS code linked with the theme functionality. With the only piece of code you've posted I can't give you other advice.